# Java stream collect check if result would contain element

Tags: java, java-stream

As I couldn't find anything related to this, I am wondering if streams even allow this.

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72255543/7109162) to another question, I have following code to add elements to a result list, only if the result list doesn't already contain it:

```
List<Entry<List<Integer>, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(diffMap.entrySet());
list.sort(Entry.comparingByValue());
List<List<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> entry2 : list) {
    if (!checkResultContainsElement(resultList, entry2.getKey()))
        resultList.add(entry2.getKey());
}
```

`checkResultContainsElement` method:

```
private static boolean checkResultContainsElement(List<List<Integer>> resultList, List<Integer> key) {
    List<Integer> vals = resultList.stream().flatMap(e -> e.stream().map(e2 -> e2))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return key.stream().map(e -> e).anyMatch(e -> vals.contains(e));
}
```

Now I am wondering, if this for-loop:

```
for (Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> entry2 : list) {
    if (!checkResultContainsElement(resultList, entry2.getKey()))
        resultList.add(entry2.getKey());
}
```

can be realized using streams. I don't think that `.filter()` method would work, as it would remove data from `List<Entry<List<Integer>, Integer>> list` while I don't even know if an element should be considered. I guess that a custom collector could work, but I also wouldn't know how to implement one, as the result is constantly changing with each newly added element.

I am looking for something like this (can be different if something else is better):

```
list.stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue()).collect(???);
```

where `???` would filter the data and return it as a list.

---

The values of one result list may not be contained in another one. So these lists are valid:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[12, 12, 12, 12]
```

but of these, only the first is valid:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] <-- valid
[5, 3, 7, 8] <-- invalid: 3 already exists
[12, 12, 2, 12] <-- invalid: 2 already exists
```

Comment: Does [the `distinct` method of `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()) give you what you want?

Comment: @OleV.V. it does not. I don't just want distinct elements. Assuming a `List<List<Integer>>` where each nested list can have the same elements in a different order, I need to check if the resulting list would already contain any of the integers, no matter the position. For `[1,3,5]` and `[3, 7, 9]` the `distinct()´ method would return both, while only 1 of both is valid

Comment: Please provide the question with the structure of the `Foo` class. It's not obvious from the first glance that it contains a field `value` of type `Integer`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko converted question from `Foo` to `Integer`, as the type doesn't matter to the question itself

Comment: That makes a difference in how to establish the uniqueness of lists. Since there's already an answer posted by @AshishPatil, maybe it might make sense to rollback the version of the question? (*the statement of the problem is totally up to you, it's only a proposition*)

Comment: A result list is considered unique, only if none if its elements are already existing in any previously returned result list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we put aside for a moment the details on whether implementation will be stream-based or not, the existing implementation of how uniqueness of the values of incoming lists is being checked can be improved.

We can gain a significant performance improvement by maintaining a `Set` of previously encountered values.

I.e. *values* from each *list* that was added to the resulting list would be stored in a *set*. And in order to ensure uniqueness of every incoming *list*, its values would be checked against the *set*.

Since operations of a stream pipeline should be stateless, as well as collector shouldn't hold a state (*i.e. changes should happen only inside its mutable container*). We can approach this problem by defining a container that will encompass a resulting list of lists of `Foo` and a set of foo-values.

I've implemented this container as a Java 16 record:

```
public record FooContainer(Set<Integer> fooValues, List<List<Foo>> foosList) {
    public void tryAdd(List<Foo> foos) {
        if (!hasValue(foos)) {
            foos.forEach(foo -> fooValues.add(foo.getValue()));
            foosList.add(foos);
        }
    }
    
    public boolean hasValue(List<Foo> foos) {
        return foos.stream().map(Foo::getValue).anyMatch(fooValues::contains);
    }
}
```

The record shown above would is used as a mutable container of a custom collector created with `Colloctors.of()`. Collector's `accumulator` make's use of `tryAdd()` method defined by the container. And the `finisher` extracts the *resulting list* from the container.

*Note* that this operation is not parallelizable, hence `combiner` of the collector throws an `AssertionError`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<List<Foo>, Integer> diffMap =
        Map.of(List.of(new Foo(1), new Foo(2), new Foo(3)), 1,
               List.of(new Foo(1), new Foo(4), new Foo(5)), 2,
               List.of(new Foo(7), new Foo(8), new Foo(9)), 3);
    
    List<List<Foo>> result = diffMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collector.of(
            () -> new FooContainer(new HashSet<>(), new ArrayList<>()),
            FooContainer::tryAdd,
            (left, right) -> {throw new AssertionError("The operation isn't parallelizable");},
            FooContainer::foosList
        ));

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[[Foo{1}, Foo{2}, Foo{3}], [Foo{7}, Foo{8}, Foo{9}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:-

```
 list.stream().
sorted(Entry.comparingByValue()).
collect(ArrayList<List<Foo>>::new,(x,y)->!checkResultContainsElement(x, y.getKey()),(x,y)->x.add(y.getKey()));
```

Comment: Had to make some adjustments for type errors, but ultimately it seems to work as needed: `return list.stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue()).collect(ArrayList::new, (x, y) -> { if (!checkResultContainsElement(x, y.getKey())) x.add(y.getKey()); }, (x, y) -> x.addAll(y));`

Comment: glad to know, it worked for you!